# Docker init-db.js throwing SyntaxError: "" string literal contains an unescaped line break :

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker-compose to containerize a flask API. The API connects to MongoDb to fetch data, so I included a link to it in the docker-compose.yml. Here is the docker-compose file:

```yaml
app:
  build: .
  command: python -u app.py
  ports:
    - "5000:5000"
  volumes:
    - .:/app
// Link to db.
  links:
    - db
// db information
db:
  image: mongo:latest
  hostname: test_mongodb
  environment:
    - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=Exploit_Resources
    - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
    - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
  volumes:
    // Connection to init-db.js which will house data.
    - ./init-db.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-db.js:ro
  ports:
    - 27017:27017
```

The init-db.js has code similar to this:

```js
db = db.getSiblingDB("name_of_db");
db.name_of_collection.drop();



db.EDB.insertMany([
    {
        "_id":"9",
        "file":"exploits/windows/dos/9.c",
        "name":"Apache 2.x - Memory Leak",
        "date":"2003-04-09",
        "author":"Matthew Murphy",
        "type":"dos",
        "platform":"windows",
        "port":"",
        "CVE":['CVE-2003-0132']
    },
    {
        "_id":"37060",
        "file":"exploits/windows/dos/37060.html",
        "name":"Microsoft Internet Explorer 11 - Crash (PoC) (1)",
        "date":"2015-05-19",
        "author":"Garage4Hackers",
        "type":"dos",
        "platform":"windows",
        "port":"",
        "CVE":[]
    },
    {
        "_id":"11",
        "file":"exploits/linux/dos/11.c",
        "name":"Apache 2.0.44 (Linux) - Remote Denial of Service",
        "date":"2003-04-11",
        "author":"Daniel Nystram",
        "type":"dos",
        "platform":"linux",
        "port":"",
        "CVE":['CVE-2003-0132']
    },
    {
        "_id":"13",
        "file":"exploits/windows/dos/13.c",
        "name":"Chindi Server 1.0 - Denial of Service",
        "date":"2003-04-18",
        "author":"Luca Ercoli",
        "type":"dos",
        "platform":"windows",
        "port":"",
        "CVE":[]
    },
]);
```

This should work, but running docker-compose up gives the following error:

```
db_1   | SyntaxError: "" string literal contains an unescaped line break :
db_1   | @/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-db.js:60708:37
db_1   | failed to load: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-db.js
db_1   | exiting with code -3
```

Is there any way to resolve this error? I believe it is originating from the insertMany() method. I am fairly new to javascript, so I may be overlooking something obvious. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is in your docker-compose file. Try to change it for the file below:

```
app:
  build: .
  command: python -u app.py
  ports:
    - "5000:5000"
  volumes:
    - .:/app
// Link to db.
  links:
    - db
// db information
db:
  image: mongo:latest
  hostname: test_mongodb
  environment:
    - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=Exploit_Resources
    - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
    - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
  volumes:
    // Connection to init-db.js which will house data.
    - ./init-db.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-db.js
  ports:
    - 27017:27017
```

I just removed `:ro` in the end of your entry-point path.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried removing the :ro at the end of the path and it did not work. I'll keep it in mind though.

Comment: Did you try the `init-db.js` in your development environment? Apparently, there is no error in the script, but the problem regards to that file as the error message says `failed to load: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-db.js`. Moreover, there is another tip about the syntax of some empty strings: `SyntaxError: "" string literal contains an unescaped line break`. I recommend you to edit this file again with sublime, VSCode, atom, or any other editor that allows you to detect unnecessary line breaks.

Comment: This comment helped a lot. It was an octal/unicode error with the code. Saving it in Visual Studio prompted it to detect and correct the encoding, and the program worked after that. Probably would've been stuck on this for months without this comment. Thank you!